# Why python array arr2d[:2,1:] produces following result?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The following:

```
arr2d = np.array([[5,10,15],[15,20,25],[30,35,40]])

arr2d[:2,1:]
```

Produces:

```
array([[10, 15],
       [20, 25]])
```

I would like to know how the result is calculated.

Comment: it's just multi-dimensionnal slicing

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre maybe not the best choice of duplicate for explaining  `numpy` slicing...

Comment: @JonClements Well, maybe. Not a numpy experts, I'm open to suggestions. Feel free to 1) reopen 2) add another original question and remove mine 3) do whatever you please you're the mod :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr2d[:2,1:]` means "rows up to (but not including!) 2, columns 1 to last".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to read [about Numpy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
In [54]: arr2d[:2,1:]
Out[54]:
array([[10, 15],
       [20, 25]])
```

means - give me first two rows and all columns starting from the second one (1)

```
In [56]: arr2d[:2,:]
Out[56]:
array([[ 5, 10, 15],
       [15, 20, 25]])

In [57]: arr2d[:2,1:]
Out[57]:
array([[10, 15],
       [20, 25]])
```